# What does the phrase "surge of a boost" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is a sentence from a drift race game's description:

> If you want to feel the **surge of a boost** as you enter a corner, think
>   of investing in a turbo.

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "surge of a boost" here. I know the lexical meaning of both ["surge"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/surge) and ["boost"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/boost), but they don't seem to fit here.

Answer (score 1):

From the dictionary: "surge: a sudden movement forward", "Boost: an increase or improvement".

Here the context means that the boost is the boost in speed that you get from a turbo, and the increased speed causes the car to surge forward. This is not very well written, but this is the meaning that is intended.